# sharepoint crawl rule to exclude AllItems.aspx , but get an item/document in search resu lts if queried in the search box

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I followed this blog Tips [1](http://weblogs.asp.net/coltk/archive/2011/07/19/crawl-rules-tips-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)and created a crawl rule http://.*forms/allitems.aspx and ran full crawl. I no longer get the results with AllItems.aspx.  However, if there is any document with name Something.doc in a Document Library , it no longer gets pulled in the search results.

I think what I desire is a basic functionality, like the user should not get to see Allitems.aspx in the search results but should get the item/document with names entered in the search box.

Please let me know if I am missing anything. I have already put in 24 hours...googled the max I could.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an Index Reset is required. Here's the steps I did:
 1. Add the following crawl rule to exclude: *://*allitems.aspx.
 2. Index Reset.
 3. Full Crawl.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work like you said. If I add a crawl rule excluding all "allitems.aspx" then it doesn't show any item from that document in search results. I even reset index but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a good way to do this using crawl rules.  Instead, I opted to set up a restriction on the search results web part.

In the search results web part properties, select "Change Query"

[image: Select Change Query]

Add a property filter to exclude anything with "AllItems" (and any other exclusions you want in place.

[image: Add AllItems to property filter]

Used Steve Mann's blog as a reference and for the images:  http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-removing-junk.html